# Scala: Do classes that extend a trait always take the traits properties?

Tags: scala

Given the following:

```
class TestClass extends TestTrait {
  def doesSomething() = methodValue + intValue
}

trait TestTrait {
  val intValue = 4
  val unusedValue = 5
  def methodValue = "method"
  def unusedMethod = "unused method"
}
```

When the above code runs, will TestClass actually have memory allocated to unusedValue or unusedMethod? I've used javap and I know that there exists an unusedValue and an unusedMethod, but I cannot determine if they are actually populated with any sort of state or memory allocation.

Basically, I'm trying to understand if a class ALWAYS gets all that a trait provides, or if the compiler is smart enough to only provide what the class actually uses from the trait?

If a trait always imposes itself on a class, it seems like it could be inefficient, since I expect many programmers will use traits as mixins and therefore wasting memory everywhere.

Thanks to all who read and help me get to the bottom of this!

Comment: I learned a lot from the answers, and I summed up my findings here: [Scala Traits: The Double Edged Sword](http://wp.me/p1J01L-22)

Comment: in addition to answers, if you need such kind of optimization, take a look at things like http://proguard.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 8):

Generally speaking, in languages like Scala and Java and C++, each *class* has a table of pointers to its instance methods.  If your question is whether the Scala compiler will allocate slots in the method table for `unusedMethod` then I would say yes it should.

I think your question is whether the Scala compiler will look at the body of `TestClass` and say "whoa, I only see uses of `methodValue` and `intValue`, so being a good compiler I'm going to refrain from allocating space in `TestClass`'s method table for `unusedMethod`.  But it can't really do this in general.  The reason is, `TestClass` will be compiled into a class file `TestClass.class` and this class may be used in a library by programmers that you don't even know.

And what will they want to do with your class?  This:

```
var x = new TestClass();
print(x.unusedMethod)
```

See, the thing is the compiler can't predict who is going to use this class in the future, so it puts all methods into its method table, even the ones not called by other methods in the class.  This applies to methods declared in the class or picked up via an implemented trait.

If you expect the compiler to do global system-wide static analysis and optimization over a fixed, closed system then I suppose in theory it could whittle away such things, but I suspect that would be a very expensive optimization and not really worth it.  If you need this kind of memory savings you would be better off writing smaller traits on your own. :)

Comment: So it sounds like small, concise traits are suggested, and perhaps implementing a companion object as a mechanism for dependency injection? I guess that makes sense.

Comment: I think so yes.  **However**, remember that these method tables are implemented per class, and there is usually only one instance of a class object around anyway.  So even if you create millions of objects of class `TestClass` there is only one method table in `TestClass`.  Bloated objects result from too many fields, not too many methods.

Comment: If I were to sum up the above comment, it would seem like using def instead of val/var would be preferred in traits if considering memory. Is this a fair generalization?

Comment: Actually in Scala, when you use `val` in a trait, `scalac` creates a method anyway.  You don't really have fields like you do in Java.  They are there but you can only see them with `javap -c` (as you probably already know).  Do try this though; it is interesting.  You will see calls to `TestTrait$class.methodValue` inside the decompiled bodies of `TestClass`.

Comment: A `var` clearly needs to allocate space in each instance, because of mutable state. What about a `val`, is the language restrictive enough that these don't have to be allocated per instance? Certainly a `private val` should be shared between all instances of a class.

Comment: Using `val str: String` will generate `def str(): String` and `def str_$(newStr: String)`, but it will also generate a private field in the class, so that should mean that each val will translate into state for each instance.

Comment: What about `private` unused fields? Will it be cutoff?

Comment: I just ran `javap` on a `private val` that was not used in a trait, and the implementing class still had it.

Comment: Note that, in C++, a `template` is compiled when referred to, instead of being just an object linked to. That means a template doesn't occupy space on the final binary if never used, as well as occupy space multiple times if used with multiple parameters.

Answer (score 5):

It may be easiest to think about how Scala implements traits at the JVM level:

- An interface is generated with the same name as the trait, containing all the trait's method signatures
- If the trait contains only abstract methods, then nothing more is needed
- If the trait contains any concrete methods, then the definition of these will be copied into any class that mixes in the trait
- Any vals/vars will also get copied verbatim

It's also worth noting how a hypothetical `var bippy: Int` is implemented in equivalent java:

```
private int bippy; //backing field
public int bippy() { return this.bippy; } //getter
public void bippy_$eq(int x) { this.bippy = x; } //setter
```

For a `val`, the backing field is final and no setter is generated

When mixing-in a trait, the compiler doesn't analyse usage.  For one thing, this would break the contract made by the interface.  It would also take an unacceptably long time to perform such an analysis. This means that you *will* always inherit the cost of the backing fields from any vals/vars that get mixed in.

As you already hinted, if this is a problem then the solution is just use `def`s in your traits.

There are several other benefits to such an approach and, thanks to the uniform access principle, you can always override such a method with a `val` further down in the inheritance hierarchy if you need to.